# I have a button having input type submit want to validate the form using MVC jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 application I have a input type submit button but I am preventing it's nature , `e.preventDefault ()` in my jquery and making an AJAX POST call

```
('#submit').click(function(e){})
```

I want to validate whole form for required values before this call, and then only proceed further ..

I am able to do this if I do not use this function `('#submit').click(function(e){});` ie. by using simple input submit button the form getting validated automatically by jquery ,

How can I use same functionality. in this case where I am making ajax call on submit button.
I used this but it not working!!

```
$("#userform").validate();
$("#userform").valid()
```

Comment: `if ($("#userform").valid()) { make ajax call } else { return; }`

Comment: it is true always @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then your form is valid! (or you have not setup the form correctly)

Comment: validate your form inside this method ('#submit').click(function(e){}) before submitting.

Comment: normal submit button working perfectly on it but not this .. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you have have an error with your code. Show the code you tried.

Comment: HI @AammadUllah I am doing a ajax call on this button click but want to make sure drop down should be selected or else it show a message .

Comment: Don't understand clearly whats your problem is ? Do you added action="javascript:void(0)" in your form ?

Comment: I have a button and it makes an ajax call , i want form should be validated before call made, else it show some message.. on ther other pages where i have normal submit button in form, the validation working but not in this case ,here I am just making ajax call i want same  jquery validation here with this normal button @AammadUllah

Comment: post your code here

Comment: that i cant .. any other way.. @AammadUllah

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate loaded then:

```
   $("#registerUserForm").submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.OverWatch.worker.postUserData(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                 //callback
                })
            }

            return false;
        })

    postUserData: function (url, data, callback) {

        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

                if (callback) {
                    callback(data);
                    $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
                }

            },
            error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            }
        });
```